# Magento Blank Home Page

Tags: magento2.3.3

today i have installed an extension "mageplaza banner slider" using following composer command

```
composer require mageplaza/module-banner-slider
```

after running this command

```
Using version ^2.0 for mageplaza/module-banner-slider
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing mageplaza/module-core (1.4.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing mageplaza/module-banner-slider (2.0.3): Loading from cache
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

after setup:upgrade when i had refreshed my home page all i got is a blank home page. anyone who ever faced this issue or know anything about this. Thanks

Comment: Can u please remove extension and then run command again and check everyting working fine there. if yes then add module again and also upgrade latest Mageplaza_Core module. and then check

Comment: i think magento 2.3.3 is not stable with the module having core functionality..is it?

Comment: Possible but not sure. Mageplaza upgrading Core module every time. So you need to upgrade core module and check may be it will work for you

Comment: this was lattest i had installed using composer

Comment: wait i will try to disable module then will let you know

Comment: I would suggest, please check log files and if you are getting any error then you need to fix it.